# How to style DialogPreference with a custom theme?

Tags: android, styles, themes

In my application I was using Theme.Holo and Theme.Holo.Light without any issues. When Holo theme is used and I click on a DialogPreference/ListPreference, a popped dialog is also themed with Holo. Same for the Holo.Light. But when PreferencesActivity is styled with my custom theme, which is derived from Holo.Light, all dialogs are themed with Holo.Light. I think I am missing somthing in my theme. Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Here is my theme code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Generated with http://android-holo-colors.com -->
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <style name="GreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/edit_text_holo_light</item>

    <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextViewGreenTheme</item>

    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/btn_check_holo_light</item>

    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/btn_radio_holo_light</item>

    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonGreenTheme</item>

    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonGreenTheme</item>

    <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerGreenTheme</item>

    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/TabWidgetGreenTheme</item>

    <item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/ProgressBarGreenTheme</item>

    <item name="android:seekBarStyle">@style/SeekBarGreenTheme</item>

    <item name="android:buttonStyleToggle">@style/ToggleGreenTheme</item>

    <item name="android:listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>

    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background_holo_light</item>

    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_holo</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Greenactionbar</item>

    <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/ButtonBarButtonStyleGreenTheme</item>

    <item name="android:preferenceStyle">@style/TimePickerDialogFragmentGreen</item>
  </style>

      <style name="TimePickerDialogFragmentGreen" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
         <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/edit_text_holo_light</item>

    <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextViewGreenTheme</item>

    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/btn_check_holo_light</item>

    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/btn_radio_holo_light</item>

    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonGreenTheme</item>

    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonGreenTheme</item>

    <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerGreenTheme</item>

    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/TabWidgetGreenTheme</item>

    <item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/ProgressBarGreenTheme</item>

    <item name="android:seekBarStyle">@style/SeekBarGreenTheme</item>

    <item name="android:buttonStyleToggle">@style/ToggleGreenTheme</item>

    <item name="android:listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>

    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background_holo_light</item>

    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_holo</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Greenactionbar</item>

    <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/ButtonBarButtonStyleGreenTheme</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: *But when PreferencesActivity is styled with my custom theme, which is derived from Holo.Light, all dialogs are themed with Holo.Light.* - and what do you expect to happen especially as you extendd from `Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog`!?? For `DialogPrefrence` the preference is declared by `dialogPreferenceStyle` which points to `Preference.Holo.DialogPreference`. That style is limited so you need to make your own `DialogPreference`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [this rather unformatted but otherwise nice answer](http://askproblem.com/question/applying-appcompat-theme-to-individual-preferences-in-a-preferencefragment/#answer-380258).

The gist is that `DialogPreference`s are `AlertDialog`s created without [the `theme` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29810469/1666398), which means they apply which ever theme `android:alertDialogTheme` points to.

So I extended my theme like this to have the dialog themed:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/yellow_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/yellow_a700</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/purple_400</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/yellow_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/yellow_a700</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/purple_400</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

The `colorPrimary`, `colorPrimaryDark` and `colorAccent` in the `AppTheme` were the colours I wanted to have applied to the dialog as well.

Note that I needed the `android:windowMinWidthMinor` to prevent the dialog from collapsing horizontally.

Comment: I read and tried so many solutions, but this one works. Thanks for contributing this. I hope this saves someone else from wasting the hours that I have on such a simple thing.

Comment: @snapfractalpop Thx for the kind words! Iirc, this was actually the answer I created this account for :) Super glad this was helpful to you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have clarifying questions, but can't ask them because of low rate. So: 
1.Does your first style work correctly? 
2.Are you sure, that theme  @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog has all items, you declared in TimePickerDialogFragmentGreen?For example:

```
<item name="android:tabWidgetStyle"> @style/TabWidgetGreenTheme</item>
```

3. Have you tried the idea proposed by **Luksprog**

And finally: I used something like that to create custom style for my EditTexts:

```
 <style name="EditTextStyle" parent="@style/Indents">
 <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
 <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
 <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
 <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
<style name="Indents" parent="@style/Margins">
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/activity_vertical_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/activity_vertical_padding</item>
</style>
<style name="Margins">
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin </item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin </item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin </item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin </item>
</style>
```