# How to change spinner, text and button color of material AlertDialog and ProgressDialog

Tags: android, themes

My app extends `Theme.AppCompat.Light` and the material-styled dialogs appear with white background, black text color, and green buttons (spinner in `ProgessDialog` is also green).

I would like to change the color and font of the text, and also the color of the buttons and spinner.

How can I do it?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455919/material-design-not-styling-alert-dialogs) post but the XML solution doesn't work for me and the other answers are third party libs that don't have a `ProgressDialog`.

Thanks!

Comment: Figure this out yet?  I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

To have the whole "Material Experience" you should use the latest AppCompat everywhere. Instead of `android.app.AlertDialog` use `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` to target devices < 21.

It is enough just to set your AppTheme up correctly like in the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <!-- This is the interesting part -->
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog</item>
    <item name="dialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog</item>
</style>

<!-- Style the dialog like the normal AppTheme -->
<style name="AppTheme.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```