# Android Alert Dialog with extra background

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-styles

I recently migrated my app to Material Design and I stumbled upon this problem with my Alert Dialogs:

[image: dialog appears to be having two backgrounds and I don't know how to get rid of the outer background]

I'm applying the dialog style like this:

`<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.AlertDialog</item>`

and **Theme.AlertDialog** looks like this:

```
<style name="Theme.AlertDialog" parent="Base.V14.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_accent_dark</item>
</style>
```

This is happening on my Kitkat device and it works fine on Lollipop. Can you help me with getting rid of that outer background?

Comment: You should use the new [android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29810469/1233652).

Comment: Well, this is actually a preference screen and the dialog that you are seeing, is actually a list preference and I don't think that I can change the type of the dialog. The accepted answer works fine though...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The point is here:

```
<style name="Theme.AlertDialog" parent="Base.V14.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    ...
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_accent_dark</item>
    ...
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: a transparent background is an issue on edge devices as there is no default dialog background so the whole dialog is transparent

Comment: it's makes transparent background on all devices but need only remove weird border. How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

As [ironman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6343685/ironman) told me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738437/weird-behavior-when-applying-theme-to-dialog-under-api-21), be sure that you import the right class.

Right : `import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;`

Wrong : `import android.app.AlertDialog;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the theme in parent

```
AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below styles . You have to customise background also.

```
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Using below also works

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Also You can set in your code by using

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

and this should be before *setContentView*

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
```

Comment: Thank you, the only thing that I had to do was to add <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item> to my Theme.AlertDialog. As pointed out by SilentKnight in his answer.

Comment: the solution doesn't seem to work for samsung edge devices

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same symptom but for me it was actually that I had used the standard frameworks AlertDialog (and its Builder) instead of android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog, switching to use the one from the support library fixed the issue for me.