# Android : How to get rid of weird border around progress dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, progressdialog

I have made my custom style for progress dialog, however it has weird borders around it.

[image: progress dialog]

Here is the theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

Any ideas why there is such weird background ?

Comment: it's progress dialog and not AlertDialog.

Comment: Remove `<item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>`.  It's not the correct way to set the background drawable for a `ProgessDialog`

Comment: @JaredRummler But then it's just whit, and also with white ugly borders. How to get desired blue look correctly?

Answer (score 8):

To remove the colored or white border around the progress dialog have the dialog use a theme that defines a transparent windowBackground

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

When creating the dialog use this theme:

```
new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add:

```
your_progress_dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

to your java.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What android version are you developing for?

Comment: Android 4.4  api level 19

Comment: Please add <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item> to your styles.

Comment: still same weird border

Answer (score 1):

it's related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406902/android-alert-dialog-with-extra-background).
But in contrary to alert dialog there is no AppCompat support to ProgressDialog.
I didn't manage to solve the problem , its possible to use the deprected THEME_HOLO_LIGHT

```
ProgressDialog dialog= new ProgressDialog(this,ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
```

but you loose all the benefits of AppCompat (like color accent).

Comment: Thanks, this was the quickest fix and does actually work (unlike some other answers here). I use it only when `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT`.

Answer (score 0):

Create Two Style

### 1) API Level less then equal 19

```
  <style name="AppAlertTheme19" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/btngreen</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@null</item>
    </style>
```

### 2) API Level greater than 19

```
<style name="AppAlertTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/btngreen</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@null</item>
    </style>
```

### 3)and init progress view like this

```
public class ProgressDialogCustom extends ProgressDialog {
    public ProgressDialogCustom(Context context) {
        super(context, getStyle());
        setMessage("Please Wait ...");
        setCancelable(false);
    }

    private static int getStyle() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            return R.style.AppAlertTheme;
        } else {
            return R.style.AppAlertTheme19;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to answer this question, but as I was facing same problem, I resolved it as follows:
I created 2 styles one for above lollipop and one for below it.

**API Level greater than 19**

```
<style name="AppAlertTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

**API Level less than 19**

```
<style name="AppAlertTheme_api19" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
     <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/nlue</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
        <item name="android:bottomBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:bottomDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:bottomMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:centerBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:centerDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:centerMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:fullBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:fullDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:topBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:topDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Then used this style as follows:

```
public int getProgressDailogStyle(){
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      return R.style.AppAlertTheme;
  } else {
      return R.style.AppAlertTheme_api19;
  }
}
```

and finally

```
   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, getProgressDailogStyle());
```

Hope this helps you..