# AlertDialog not using material design correctly?

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog

In the material design [documentation](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs) it says the content padding of the dialog's text should be 24dp, but if you construct a simple AlerDialog with following code there isn't any bottom padding as you can see in the screenshot.

[image: AlertDialog]

```
    public class MainActivity extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity { 

      @Override
      public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      final android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setTitle("title");
      builder.setMessage("asdf asöldkfasölkdf öasdklfjöa aösdkföa sdköf masjdö lmasjködf mjaösk maöskd mjaösk fmaöskmaöskmföasföalk maölskjd möaslkd möas mjaös m").setCancelable(true)
             .setNeutralButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                      dialog.cancel();
                  }
              }).setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onCancel(final DialogInterface dialog) {
                   MainActivity.sMessageDialogId = 0;
                 }
      });
      builder.show();
     }
    }
```

Comment: Use android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog instead of android.app.AlertDialog. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455919/material-design-not-styling-alert-dialogs/29810469#29810469

Comment: It already is the support version

Comment: So ridiculous that so much of the framework itself doesn't follow the Material guidelines. Did you ever find a solution without having to set a custom view on the dialog builder? Many of the other padding dimensions don't quite match up to the guidelines either.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following the code to check the version compatibility,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
} else {
        builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
}
```

Comment: You should use android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.

Comment: I am calling the code inside an android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; and for this activity only Theme.AppCompat.xy can be used

Answer (score 0):

Try this `builder.setPadding(24, 24, 24, 24);`

Comment: I know that this could work, but why is not the standard being implemented already?

Comment: What API is `builder.setPadding` referring to? I don't see that in the `AlertDialog.Builder` docs.